# How to use functions in order

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, xcode-ui-testing

```
import XCTest

class TestClass: XCTestCase
{

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp() 
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
        continueAfterFailure = true
        // UI tests must launch the application that they test. Doing this in setup will make sure it happens for each test method.
        XCUIApplication().launch()

        // UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.layer.speed = 100
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.layer.speed = 100

        // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation - required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample()
    {
    }

    func testA1_TC8InvalidEmailAndPasswordTC8_A1()
    {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        let emailIdTextField = app.textFields["Email ID"]
        emailIdTextField.tap()

        if emailIdTextField.value as! String != ""
        {
            emailIdTextField.clearAndEnterText(emailIdTextField.value as! String)
        }

        emailIdTextField.typeText("test@gmail.com")

        let passwordSecureTextField = app.secureTextFields["Password"]
        passwordSecureTextField.tap()
        passwordSecureTextField.typeText("dgbnnnbb")
        app.buttons["Login"].tap()
        app.buttons["OK"].tap()
    }

    func testA2_TC9KeepAllFieldBlankTC9_A2()
    {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        let emailIdTextField = app.textFields["Email ID"]
        emailIdTextField.tap()

        if emailIdTextField.value as! String != ""
        {
            emailIdTextField.clearAndEnterText(emailIdTextField.value as! String)
        }

        app.textFields["Email ID"].tap()
        let passwordSecureTextField = app.secureTextFields["Password"]
        app.secureTextFields["Password"].tap()

        if passwordSecureTextField.value as! String != ""
        {    
            passwordSecureTextField.clearAndEnterText(passwordSecureTextField.value as! String)
        }

        app.secureTextFields["Password"].tap()
        app.buttons["Login"].tap()
        app.buttons["OK"].tap()
    }

    func testTC10ValidUsernameAndInvalidPasswordTC10C()
    {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        let emailIdTextField = app.textFields["Email ID"]
        emailIdTextField.tap()

        if emailIdTextField.value as! String != ""
        {
            emailIdTextField.clearAndEnterText(emailIdTextField.value as! String)
        }

        emailIdTextField.typeText("gfdedkff@gmail.com")

        let passwordSecureTextField = app.secureTextFields["Password"]
        passwordSecureTextField.tap()
        passwordSecureTextField.typeText("grtegrgrtst")

        let moreNumbersKey = app.keys["more, numbers"]
        moreNumbersKey.tap()
        passwordSecureTextField.typeText("@123")
        app.buttons["Login"].tap()
        app.buttons["OK"].tap()
    }
```

I have multiple functions in test class. I want to use these functions one by one (synchronously) in order because function one result is function two output or parameter. Can you help me to find-out the solution?

Comment: Please show respect for readers, and only post _relevant_ code in your question. Read [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

in our project we had a similar issue. You cannot force tests execution order on XCTest. We resolved our problem by a method that describes all steps for each test, then we could execute whole path every time and check only specific points in each test.

To check if it works for example code you provided, I created test app [>>here<<](https://github.com/dzoanb/login-form). The repository is on GitHub and required a bit of work, so I would be grateful if you could take a look at it. There is a basic form I needed for testing and as little code as I could write to test my solution. The most important part are UI tests, you can see two versions there. One in vanilla XCTest and one refactored to use a library I'm developing with my colleagues - [AutoMate](https://github.com/PGSSoft/AutoMate). It let me clean up the code.

As I was testing this solution in your case, it came to me that you may be tied with a state persisted between launches. That's why I introduced option which can be passed to the application.

```swift
var app: XCUIApplication!
override func setUp()
{
    super.setUp()
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

    // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
    continueAfterFailure = true
    // UI tests must launch the application that they test. Doing this in setup will make sure it happens for each test method.
    app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launchEnvironment["NUMBER_OF_ATTEMPTS"] = "0"
    app.launch()

    // UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.layer.speed = 100
    //        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.layer.speed = 100
}

func testA1_TC8InvalidEmailAndPasswordTC8_A1()
{
    setUp(forTest: 1)
    // Do Your asserts here
}

func testA2_TC9KeepAllFieldBlankTC9_A2()
{
    setUp(forTest: 2)
    // Do Your asserts here
}

func testTC10ValidUsernameAndInvalidPasswordTC10C()
{
    setUp(forTest: 3)
    // Do Your asserts here
}

func setUp(forTest testsCount: Int) {
    let credentials = [
        ("test@gmail.com", "dgbnnnbb"),
        ("", ""),
        ("gfdedkff@gmail.com", "grtegrgrtst")
    ]
    let emailIdTextField = app.textFields["Email ID"]
    let passwordSecureTextField = app.secureTextFields["Password"]

    for (no, (email, password)) in credentials.prefix(upTo: testsCount).enumerated() {
        fill(emailIdTextField, with: email)
        switch no {
        case 0:
            fill(passwordSecureTextField, with: password, clear: false)
        case 1:
            fill(passwordSecureTextField, with: password)
            passwordSecureTextField.tap()
        case 2:
            fill(passwordSecureTextField, with: password, clear: false)
            let moreNumbersKey = app.keys["more, numbers"]
            moreNumbersKey.tap()
            passwordSecureTextField.typeText("@123")
        default:
            break
        }
        app.buttons["Login"].tap()
        app.buttons["OK"].tap()
    }
}

func fill(_ field: XCUIElement, with text: String, clear: Bool = true) {
    field.tap()

    if clear, let stringValue = field.value as? String, stringValue != ""
    {
        field.clearAndEnterText(field.value as! String)
    }

    field.typeText(text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This testing framework that you're using (XCTest provided by Apple) is designed such that tests are independent of one another. This is for very (many) good reasons that is out of scope for this answer.

You can do it but you'll be fighting the framework the whole way and or losing out on key functionality provided to you by Xcode and the XCTest framework.

A quick an easy way to do this, is to just have one `test()` func. Then write all your individual tests as helper functions and call them sequentially within `func test()`.

So...

```
func testSequentially() {
    assertThisFirst()
    assertThisSecond()
}

func assertThisFirst() {
    // Some test
}

func assertThisSecond() {
    // Some other test
}
```

Now let me reassert that this is not a good way of running tests. You miss out on the ability to run individual tests. You miss out on a lot of nice GUI in Xcode for inspecting tests. Your tests will be **a lot** harder to debug when failures inevitably do occur. On and on and on... I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: Thanks For given Answer But Dear sir, if i call [assertThisFirst() and assertThisSecond()] these two functions in testSequentially(). Then i don't get the result of these two functions . In that case, i only get the result of testSequentially() Test Case. So can u give me another solution for my question.

Comment: That was my point. This testing framework is not built to run tests in a known or standardized order. Doing it requires workarounds and you lose out on nice things like getting individual test results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
let randomFunction = [test1(),test2(),test3()]
testMethodA()
testMethodB()
testMethodC()
```